# How should I get a copy of this object in rust?

Tags: rust, copy

I've got a small program that is supposed to print out the response status of an html get request and also print out the raw html of that response. (I am using the latest version of the reqwest crate for this)

```
fn main() {
    let req = reqwest::blocking::get("https://www.rust-lang.org");
    let rawhtml = req.clone().unwrap().text().unwrap();
    let status = req.unwrap().status();

    println!("status: {}\n\n", status);
    println!("{}", rawhtml);
}
```

running with `cargo run` gives me error[E0599] saying

> method cannot be called on `Result<reqwest::blocking::Response, reqwest::Error>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds

So if I cannot clone the object then how am I to use more than one of its functions that consumes "self"? I don't want to have to make multiple get requests when all the info I need should be in one.

Comment: Maybe first call `status()` and then `text()`, [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=716484cfe21be2f49642bc6bdbf61d74)?

Comment: @user4815162342 I'm going to want to add calls later that consume as well.

Comment: Can you show an example that you'd like to work (using those other calls) and doesn't?

Comment: Unwrap the `Result` once and for all, _then_ call the methods on the unwrapped response: `let req = req.unwrap(); let raw_html = req.text().unwrap(); let status = req.status();` (although as pointed out by @user4815162342, it would make more sense to check the status before attempting to get the text).

Comment: @Jmb It won't work in the order you suggested because `Response::text` [consumes self](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.4/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.text) - which is why I instructed the OP to first check the status and then check the status. But the OP needs to call _additional_ methods that consume `self`, so I'm curious which  those are, because all the methods I see are _alternatives_ to `text()` (e.g. `bytes()`, `json()`), not something you'd want to call after calling `text()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, [`reqwest::blocking::Response`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.4/reqwest/blocking/struct.Response.html) doesn't implement [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) or provide an alternative, so "getting a copy" is *not an option;* you need to structure your program so it doesn't need a copy.

The problem you're having with your current code is not mainly with the [`Response`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.4/reqwest/blocking/struct.Response.html); it's that you're calling [`Result::unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.unwrap), which *does* consume the `Result` it's called on — *in order to give you its contents.* The right thing to do here is to call `unwrap` only once.

```rust
    let req = reqwest::blocking::get("https://www.rust-lang.org")
        .unwrap();
    let rawhtml = req.text().unwrap();
    let status = req.status();
```

This still won't compile, but that's because you are calling the methods in the wrong order: you must ask for whatever things you need from the *headers* of the response before using the *body*. This is not an arbitrary constraint; it's because HTTP gives you that information in that order, and so having the API work this way allows `reqwest` to not need to store the entire response as it is downloaded — the [`Response`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.4/reqwest/blocking/struct.Response.html) object is not just an unchanging data structure but actually represents the response *as it is being sent to your computer.*

This version will work:

```rust
    let req = reqwest::blocking::get("https://www.rust-lang.org")
        .unwrap();
    let status = req.status();
    let rawhtml = req.text().unwrap();
```

`status` and `rawhtml` both implement [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html), so you can keep those around and make copies as much as you need, unlike the `Response`.

(Disclaimer: I haven't actually used `reqwest` myself; this answer is based on reading the docs and source, and general Rust principles.)